# Gephi: edges partition based on attribute

Tags: gephi, graph-visualization

Using Gephi 0.9.1, I want to colour my edges based on an attribute similar to how it is shown in the following image (note that this image relates to Gephi 0.8.2, but conceptually it is the same task).

[image: graph partition]

The attribute that I would like to use has been imported in the spreadsheet e.g. t1 or t2 in the below image.

[image: gephi data laboratory]

However, in the relevant field I only get the option of weight.

[image]

How can I use an attribute from a column in the data laboratory?

Answer (score 0):

The attributes t1, t2 etc are node attributes not edge attributes.
Weight is an edge attribute, in the data lab table switch to edges to see the attributes for edge colouring.